# Foreign Keys are not getting assigned - Django

Tags: python, django

i am new to this, any recommendations are accepted, my main problem is that i have some foreign keys that are getting assigned in my database.

As you can see the last 4 models are related to the patient model through a Foreign Key, these are the fields that are not getting assigned in my project.

## Models

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    Codigo = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None,null=False)
    Nombres = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    Apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    Fecha_Nacimiento = models.DateField()
    Numero_Telefonico = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=' ')
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=True,blank=True,default=' ')
    Genero = models.ForeignKey(Gender,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default=None,null=True)
    Nacionalidad = models.ForeignKey(Nationality,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default=None,null=True)
    Estado_Civil = models.ForeignKey(CivilStatus,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,null=True)
    Ocupacion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Lugar_de_Procedencia = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Lugar_de_Residencia = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nombres + ' ' + self.Apellidos

class MedicalInfo(models.Model):
    Expediente = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    Sangre = models.ForeignKey(BloodType,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default=None,null=True)
    Peso = models.FloatField()
    Estatura = models.FloatField()
    Alergia = models.ForeignKey(Allergies,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,null=True)
    Observacion = models.CharField(max_length=500,default= ' ',null=True)
    Paciente = models.OneToOneField(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,blank=True,null=True)


class InsuranceInfo(models.Model):
    Seguro = models.ForeignKey(InsuranceCompany,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    Tipo_de_Poliza = models.ForeignKey(Policy,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    Numero_Poliza = models.IntegerField(default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    Vencimiento = models.DateField(default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    Paciente = models.OneToOneField(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,blank=True,null=True)


class Relatives(models.Model):
    Parentesco = models.ForeignKey(Family_relation, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Apellido = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Telefono = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Correo = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    Nacimiento = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    Pariente = models.OneToOneField(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nombre + ' ' + self.Apellido

class Background(models.Model):
    Padecimiento = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Control = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Medicamento = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Paciente = models.OneToOneField(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
```

These are my forms, you can see that i exluded the 'Paciente' or 'Pariente' field (depending on the name of the model) in some of them because i want to assigned that field a value through a view which i will show you above the forms section.

## Forms

```
class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'Fecha_Nacimiento': DateInput()
        }

class RelativesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Relatives
        exclude = ('Pariente',)
        widgets = {
            'Nacimiento': DateInput()
        }

class MedicalInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MedicalInfo
        exclude = ('Paciente',)

class InsuranceInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InsuranceInfo
        exclude = ('Paciente',)

class BackgroundForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Background
        exclude = ('Paciente',)
```

This is the view i was talking about, in here i attempted to create a view containing all those forms and show it as one, the 'Patient' i created i this form is the one i want to assign to the field i excluded in the forms, that's why i excluded it because i wanted to assigned it manually, this is my attempt, i don't know what i am doing wrong or is missing. Any recommendations or solutions are accepted. Thanks!

## Views

```
def PatientFormView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        patientinfo = PatientForm(data=request.POST)
        medicalinfo = MedicalInfoForm(data=request.POST)
        insuranceinfo = InsuranceInfoForm(data=request.POST)
        backgroundinfo = BackgroundForm(data=request.POST)
        first_relative = RelativesForm(data=request.POST)


        if patientinfo.is_valid() and medicalinfo.is_valid() and backgroundinfo.is_valid() and insuranceinfo.is_valid() and first_relative.is_valid():

            patient = patientinfo.save()
            patient.save()

            medicalinfo.save(commit=False)
            medicalinfo.Paciente = patient
            medicalinfo.save()

            backgroundinfo.save(commit=False)
            backgroundinfo.Paciente = patient
            backgroundinfo.save()

            insuranceinfo.save(commit=False)
            insuranceinfo.Paciente = patient
            insuranceinfo.save()

            first_relative.save(commit=False)
            first_relative.Pariente = patient
            first_relative.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('patients'))


    else:
        patientinfo = PatientForm()
        medicalinfo = MedicalInfoForm()
        insuranceinfo = InsuranceInfoForm()
        backgroundinfo = BackgroundForm()
        first_relative = RelativesForm()

    return render(request,'patients/patient_form.html',context={'patientinfo':patientinfo,'backgroundinfo':backgroundinfo,'first_relative':first_relative,'medicalinfo':medicalinfo,'insuranceinfo':insuranceinfo})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update form instances. Change them as:

```
insurance = insuranceinfo.save(commit=False)
insurance.Paciente = patient
insurance.save()
```

Apply this approach to other models.

Comment: Thanks @Deniz Kaplan, this was my error! Thank you so much!